# Dropbox folder under Program Files

Tags: dropbox

are there any ways that we can change the Dropbox folder under the Program Files folder in Win 7? 
I use a desktop PC with only permissions to store file under the folder Program Files/MyApp . However, Dropbox keeps saying that the Dropbox folder can't be located under Program Files. Thanks

Comment: Is there a good reason you'd want it in Program Files? Program Files is a special folder meant for the internal use of applications.

Comment: Because his program only stores the files "under the folder Program Files/MyApp"

Comment: Sounds like you are running into a Dropbox limitation; and it sounds like it is by design.  Recommend you seek support for Dropbox via their support network.

Comment: It sounds like your Windows systems administrator is incompetent.